# Using merged variablenames

Tags: macros

I have variables in the form: dim1a, dim1b, dim1c...; dim2a, dim2b, dim2c...

I want to create a `\newcommand` with the dimension as argument, but constant a/b/c.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\newcount\lengtha \lengtha = 500
\newcount\lengthb \lengthb = 800
\newcount\speeda \speeda = 100
\newcount\speedb \speedb = 600

\newcommand{\dim}[1]{\#1a}

\divide\dim{length} by 10 
\divide\dim{speed} by 10 

\end{document}
```

I cant figure out how to transport e.g the string "\speed" to form `\speeda` without latex looking for the (non-existing) variable `\speed`.

Comment: LaTeX offers `\@nameuse{#1a}`, but as you see from the `@` in the name, it's for use in packages only, or you need to say `\makeatletter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\newcount` is a TeX-primitive. Instead you should use the LaTeX2e command `\newcounter`. However the command `\newcounter` can only handle integer expressions. Based on your name definition I guess you want to use dimensions. So the correct command is `\newlength`.

If you want to compute floating points I recommend the expl3 module `l3fp` or the older package `fp`. The package `pgf` offers some equal material for computing.

Comment: You proabably mean `\newlength`

Comment: @mrf: Indeed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Stephan has already mentioned `\@nameuse` from the LaTeX kernel. The `etoolbox` package provides a user-level command  `\csuse` to generate a control sequence token:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\newcount\lengtha \lengtha = 500
\newcount\lengthb \lengthb = 800
\newcount\speeda \speeda = 100
\newcount\speedb \speedb = 600

\newcommand{\mydim}[1]{\csuse{#1a}}

\divide\mydim{length} by 10 
\divide\mydim{speed} by 10 

\end{document}
```